# Titanium Mobile: set locale (language) in app

Tags: mobile, internationalization, locale, titanium

I don't quite get how the user locale is handled in Titanium Mobile.
I have now set up two language files, and at least the English version is working fine. Now I would like to be able to set the locale within the app, so a user may change the language of the app.

How is this done?
And what is the best way to handle other locale issues such as currency, date formatting, etc.?

Thanks you for your answers!
Cheers
Chris

Comment: If your previous screenshots are any indication I assume you are building a iOS app which isn't supported as well in TiLocal as android. Specifically you won't have access to currencyCode or currencySymbol. You can however format telephone numbers and I don't see any docs about formatting dates however you can just write a custom JS solution for that.

Comment: Brian, thanks for your comment. They are actually. I was hoping there would be a way besides coding it all myself. Too bad I guess. Cheers

Comment: This question was asked over 4 years ago..

Answer (score 0):

You can use below modules

https://marketplace.appcelerator.com/listing?q=locale%20-#!/list/page/1/search=locale%20-

This modules helps you to follow same i18n folder string.xml and it will force the language only inside your app.

Answer (score 0):

Use and external JS library like https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js to be able to force switch language within app. The library is already quite robust.

http://i18njs.com/

Answer (score 0):

For changing the language of the app you can try this, as I am using same for the same purpose :-

I have added this in **alloy.js**

```
var language = Ti.App.Properties.getString('selectedLanguage','es');
Alloy.Globals.language = language;
Ti.Locale.setLanguage(language);
```

for changing the app language, I have created a tableView for selection on table's click listener I am changing the app language

```
if(e.index == 0){
    Alloy.Globals.language = 'es';
    Ti.App.Properties.setString('selectedLanguage','es');
}else{
    Alloy.Globals.language = 'en';
    Ti.App.Properties.setString('selectedLanguage','en');
}
```

and after all that I am refreshing my screen, in my function `updateScreenForLanguage();`

```
function updateScreenForLanguage(){
    $.Back.text = (L('Back'));
    $.Title.text = (L('Profile'));
    $.labelLanguagePreference.text = (L("Language_Preference"));    
}
```

hope this will help you. for more [Titanium internationalization](http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Internationalization)

Answer (score -1):

Titanium language locale can be use like this

```
var language = Titanium.Platform.locale;
Titanium.App.Properties.setString('locale',language);
Titanium.App.language = language;
```

Comment: `Titanium.App.language` isn't a property used by Titanium is it? What exactly should this example do? After setting `Titanium.App.Properties.setString('locale', 'de');` the value `Titanium.Platform.locale` doesn't change..

Comment: check this http://developer.appcelerator.com/apidoc/mobile/1.6.0/Titanium.Locale-module for detail

Comment: I've checked out the documentation, my question is how to use the Locale functions to be able to change the language during runtime.

Comment: This one sets property `locale` to current language and global variable `Ti.App.language` to the same value. It is quite useless